# PHP Check if string contains a letter

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am creating a login and want to allow my users to login either by username or email. How would I check if a string contains a letter, in this case @ so I can handle it correctly. Would I use `strstr` or `strpos`? Thanks!

Comment: You could use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). If a username and email couldn't both couldn't be reused though, you could put them both in the same `SELECT`, meaning you don't need to know if it's an email or user "id".

Comment: Usually, you would say that @ is a special character. `a-z` and `A-Z` are letters and `0-9` are numbers or digits to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either. Since the `@` should not appear at the start, you don't even need the `strpos` result booleanization workaround.

If you want to assert that it's a valid email address, then also try

```
filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

Answer (score 10):

To just check if string contains a letter you could use

```
if (strpos($source_string, $letter) !== false) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page for strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) (second note) states that strpos is less memory intensive than strstr if you are simply finding out whether it occurs. Therefore, use strpos.