# How to check that the first character in a string is a letter?

Tags: php, string, function, character

Looking for a function that can test whether the first given character is a 
letter.  An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you googled your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Check if string contains a letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782212/php-check-if-string-contains-a-letter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ctype_alpha()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php):

```
$string = 'any string';
$string = trim($string);//removes any spaces from beginning of the string
if(ctype_alpha($string[0]))
    echo "First character is a letter";
else 
    echo "First character is not a letter";
```

`string[0]` is the first character for your string.

`ctype_alpha()` checks if the characters are all letters.

`ctype_alpha($string[0])` checks the first character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (ctype_alpha(substr($test_me,0,1))) {
        echo "its a letter";
}
```